# To access tabbar from uiview in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, tabbar

In my application when I am getting any notification I am showing a customView. And if user touches anywhere on the screen, the view will disappear. I have a `UITabBar` with four tabs. After getting notification, when I click on the view, the 2nd tab should be selected (I may be anywhere in the app). But I am unable to select the 2nd tab. It always opens the first tab. How do I call the "didSelect item" from this customView? Following is my code. Please verify it and help me to resolve my issue.

**My code is:**

```
{
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabbarView") as? MainTabbarView
    storyBoard?.selectItem(withIndex: 3)  
}
```

**In my UITabBarController I have wrritten the following code:**

```
func selectItem(withIndex index: Int) {
    if let controller = tabBarController, let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar, let items = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
        guard index < items.count else { return }
        controller.selectedIndex = index
        controller.tabBar(tabBar, didSelect: items[index])
    }
} 

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if let items = tabBar.items {
        items.enumerated().forEach { if $1 == item { print("your index is: \($0)") } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based in your code, you are initializing a new instance of TabBarController instead of using the active one, so it really does not update your current tab bar. You can access a view controller that tabBarController owns. Then from there:

```
activeViewController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. can i write the following code ?                                            var topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            while((topVC!.presentedViewController) != nil) {
                topVC = topVC!.presentedViewController
            }
            
            topVC?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2

Comment: Yes, you can try as long as your tabBarController and view controllers are properly set, that should work.